# C# CMD with command not executed

Tags: c#, cmd

so the problem I have is, Everytime when I press Start, the console opens but doesnt put out any code in it. This is my code:

```
    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ObtainAccessToken("My Email", "My Password");
        string code = GetAccessToken();
        string strCmdText;
        strCmdText = "java -Xms512m -Xmx1g -Djava.library.path=natives/ -cp \".jar; lwjgl.jar; lwjgl_util.jar\" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft " + "My Email" + " " + code;
        Process.Start("cmd.exe", strCmdText);
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Also if i change the strCmdText with something else, nothing happens, the CMD popsup but does not output anything in it, why is this? I tried to change it too something i found on the internet but also there, it didnt show any output...

Comment: Open a command prompt and type CMD /?. You will see an option that say (more or less) `/C executes the arguments and exits`. Add it before your current arguments string

Comment: Type `cmd /?` to see why it doesn't work. CMD requires switches. Either `/c` or `/k`.

Comment: Allright, adding the /C works thanks!